# How does Indian Railways allot seats in case of change in boarding point?

Tags: tickets, indian-railways

I intend to travel on the Hampi express from SBC (Bengaluru City station) to Hospet. As only waitlisted tickets were available between these stations, I have booked my journey from Kengeri to Hospet and changed the boarding point to SBC. My ticket is currently [RAC(Reservation against Cancellation)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reservation_against_Cancellation).

How does seat allocation happen in such a situation? Is it based on the booking station or the boarding station?

Answer (score 1):

According to [Indian Railways](http://www.indianrail.gov.in/reservation_Rules.html) (scroll to the bottom)

> CHANGE OF BOARDING POINT : If a passenger desires to occupy reserved
>   accommodation from any station enroute, he would be permitted to
>   entrain at any intermediate station he chooses irrespective of the
>   distance from the starting station subject to the following conditions
>   :
>
> - A specific request must be made in writing at any computerized reservation counter and reservation made atleast 24 hours before the
>     scheduled departure of the train from the starting station.
> - **The Railway Administration reserves the right to use such accommodation from the originating station up to the station at which
>     the passenger is due to entrain.**
> - No refund will be permissible for the portion of journey not performed by the passenger.

As per rules the seat allotment is based on your boarding station.